# how to abort running build in Jenkins automatically when new build is in queue

Tags: python, jenkins, angular6

In Jenkins, If one build is currently running and next one is in pending state then what should i do so that running one should get aborted and next pending one should start running and so on.

Comment: you want to do it using some external script automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find if there are any queued builds using below API from remote,
`http://[JENKINS_URL]/queue/api/xml` [check here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API)
if there are any queued builds, get the running build number using below API,
`http://[JENKINS_URL]/job/[JOB_NAME]/lastBuild/buildNumber`
then stop the curretly running job with below API(using POST),
`http://[Jenkins_URL]/job/[Job_Name]/[Build_Number]/stop`